# How to bind a future event when using jQuery Mobile external page linking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events, jquery-on

In jQuery Mobile, the external page is linked via Ajax (i.e. the content of the external page is loaded into current page via Ajax).

The problem is: How to bind a event on the future (i.e. to be loaded) content?

Let say the content to be loaded has the following HTML input

```
<input type='text' id='foo' name='foo'>
```

How to bind a input event on it?

With just static HTML, the following code would work

```
$('#foo').on('input', function () {
...
```

Now it didn't work now since the DOM is loaded dynamically, I tried to use delegation but also not work

```
$(document).on('#foo', 'input', function () {
...
```

Any idea?

Comment: It doesn't work because that code should be `$(document).on('input', '#foo', function() {});`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the script in the external page as long as the script tag is within the data-role="page" div (Only the content of the first found data-role="page" element is loaded into the current page.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#extpagedivid", function(){
    $(document).on("input", "#foo", function(){...});
});
```

You can also include this code in the pagecreate handler of the main page as long as you are using event delegation. Make sure the ID of the input is unique across all pages that will be loaded into the main page.

Answer (score -1):

How about using `var`

```
var myFunc = function() { ... }

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#foo').on('input', myFunc );
});
```